# How can I retrieve SQL Stored Procedure Parameter's with SMO more efficently?

Tags: sql-server, performance, smo

I'm attempting to retrieve the DefaultValue of all the parameters in a StoredProcedure.  My application is build in C# .NET accessing a Microsoft SQL 2008 Database.

I use the SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters to get most of the parameter information rather efficiently however it does not return the "DefaultValue" of a parameter so I've resorted to SMO to get that particular property.

Here's my current code :

```
        Server svr = new Server(new ServerConnection(new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString)));
        StoredProcedure sp = svr.Databases["MyDatabase"].StoredProcedures["mySproc", "myScheme"];
        svr.SetDefaultInitFields(typeof(StoredProcedureParameter), "Name");
        svr.SetDefaultInitFields(typeof(StoredProcedureParameter), "DefaultValue");

        Dictionary<string, string> defaultValueLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (StoredProcedureParameter parameter in sp.Parameters)
        {
            string defaultValue = parameter.DefaultValue;
            string parameterName = parameter.Name;
            defaultValueLookup.Add(parameterName, defaultValue);
        }
```

However, this is very slow even after I added the svr.SetDefaultInitFields optimization (which did make a significant improvement ~10x improvement).

Anybody got further optimization ideas?

Comment: Just a note to any other poor souls who find themselves doing this, functions are found here:  StoredProcedure sp = svr.Databases["MyDatabase"].UserDefinedFunctions

Answer (score 3):

I had a smiliar problem and found that if you use...

```
svr.SetDefaultInitFields(typeof(StoredProcedure), false)
```

It's *way* faster. I'm asuming that with any other options it actually fetches everything but if you switch it off then just get your params the speed increase is huge. Mine when from 5-6 secs to 0.5 secs for a 10 param sp. Still not quite perfect but livable with.

**EDIT**

Since playing with this a little more I found that the `typeof(StoredProcedure)` level appraoch works the best. In my tests using the `typeof(StoreedProcedureParameter)` option was consistently 1.5 secs or so compared to the 0.5 secs or so with the `typeof(StoredProcedure)` version.

I'd be interested if anyone could tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a parser to retrieve the default values from the stored procedure, e.g. [`Microsoft.Data.Schema.ScriptDom`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gertd/archive/2008/08/21/getting-to-the-crown-jewels.aspx).